# How to add new key with new value to exist array in php ?

Tags: php, json

i'm trying to add value with key to exist array

this my array

```
{
  "object": {
    "USER_ID": "1",
    "EMAIL": "abdabughazaleh@hotmail.com",
    "FIRST_NAME": "abd",
    "LAST_NAME": "abughazaleh",
    "PICTURE": "images/users/xuhEzR6m4LvjCuKx1vAb.jpg"
  }
}
```

with json result .

i need to add element like this :

```
{
  "object": {
    "USER_ID": "1",
    "EMAIL": "abdabughazaleh@hotmail.com",
    "FIRST_NAME": "abd",
    "LAST_NAME": "abughazaleh",
    "PICTURE": "images/users/xuhEzR6m4LvjCuKx1vAb.jpg",
    "new_key": "new_value"
  }
}
```

when i trying this :

```
 array_push($ar['object'],array('new_key'=>'new_value'));
```

and this :

```
$ar['object']['new_key'] = 'new_value';
```

problem not solved for me :(

Comment: That's not an array you tried to add value in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve it using this code ,

```
  <?php   $array->object->new_key ='new_value'; ?>
```

Answer (score 5):

This is not an array, this is [json](http://php.net/manual/en/book.json.php):

```
{
  "object": {
    "USER_ID": "1",
    "EMAIL": "abdabughazaleh@hotmail.com",
    "FIRST_NAME": "abd",
    "LAST_NAME": "abughazaleh",
    "PICTURE": "images/users/xuhEzR6m4LvjCuKx1vAb.jpg"
  }
}
```

First, convert json into associative array with [`json_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php):

```
$json = '{
  "object": {
    "USER_ID": "1",
    "EMAIL": "abdabughazaleh@hotmail.com",
    "FIRST_NAME": "abd",
    "LAST_NAME": "abughazaleh",
    "PICTURE": "images/users/xuhEzR6m4LvjCuKx1vAb.jpg"
  }
}';

$json = json_decode($json, true); //true second parameter is actully for converting json into associative array
```

Than add a value to newly created array:

```
$json['object']['key'] = 'value';
```

Result of `print_r($json)`:

```
Array
(
    [object] => Array
        (
            [USER_ID] => 1
            [EMAIL] => abdabughazaleh@hotmail.com
            [FIRST_NAME] => abd
            [LAST_NAME] => abughazaleh
            [PICTURE] => images/users/xuhEzR6m4LvjCuKx1vAb.jpg
            [key] => value
        )

)
```

Than convert back to json:

```
$json = json_encode($json);
```

Reult of `echo $json;`:

```
{
"object":{
        "USER_ID":"1",
        "EMAIL":"abdabughazaleh@hotmail.com",
        "FIRST_NAME":"abd",
        "LAST_NAME":"abughazaleh",
        "PICTURE":"images\/users\/xuhEzR6m4LvjCuKx1vAb.jpg",
        "key":"value"
    }
}
```

Comment: You should really convert to an object and modify that so that you can json_encode the result and get what OP asked for as a result.